# The community page should be displayed in the Google Search page list whenever I type the community page CNAME in the google search

Tags: customer-community, seo

I created a community and deployed it in the Production org .

I have customized the url for the community with the help of godaddy

"www.shipperman.com" .This is the url.

Now my requirement is whenever I type any keyword related to the website in google page the community that I  created should be shown in the search list of google

something like: when I type salesforce in the search box the following result is shown in the google page
[image]

This is achievable by using the Napili template while building the community

But  due to my requirement I have used the visualforce template .So is there a way to achieve this requirement .Please guide me

I don't think any cding is required to achieve this requirement .This can be achieved with configuration changes only.

Comment: Hello, Please post your code or at-least list out what you tried. No one is going to give you any solutions if you ask a generic question and ask for a function. Whoever has down-voted this question please put a comment on what the person asking the question should do rather than simply down voting.

Comment: Hii @RedDevil .I have already completed the coding part. I just don't know how to proceede with the above requirement from here on.So far as I have unnderstood I think that the above functionality can be achieved without any coding

Answer (score 0):

Below link has details on how to setup SEO manually for communities.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo.htm&language=en_US&type=0

and below link explains how to setup robots.txt file

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_configure_seo.htm&type=0